# GoogleCloudMessaging - InstanceID.getInstance(), registering from client

Tags: java, android, api, cloud, messaging

I'm pretty new to programming in Java and generally programming. Right now I decided to make my own app that is supposed to utilize Google Cloud Messaging. And somehow I succeeded but then I realized I used method

```
String regid = gcm.register(PROJECT_NUMBER);
```

that is deprecated and I should now use tokens and InstanceIDs. So I tried rewriting my registration to use it but I encountered a problem with InstanceID.getInstancer(). I carefully followed all steps from documentation https://developers.google.com/instance-id/guides/android-implementation and somehow it still doesn't work.

```
String authorizedEntity = "79424738XXXX";
String scope = "GCM";
String token = InstanceID.getInstance().getToken(authorizedEntity,scope);
```

Android Studio tells me that error is:

> getInstance() - "getInstance (Context) in InstanceID cannot be applied
>   to 0"

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a working example at https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/start

```
git clone https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services.git
```

In there they do in `RegistrationIntentService.java`

```
 InstanceID instanceID = InstanceID.getInstance(this);
                String token = instanceID.getToken(getString(R.string.gcm_defaultSenderId),
                        GoogleCloudMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE, null);
```

`gcm_defaultSenderId` is your project id (`79424738XXXX`)

`this` is the `RegistrationIntentService.this`

Comment: Sadly it still doesn't work for me.

        `String projectID = "79424738XXXX";
        String token = instanceID.getToken(getString(R.string.projectID),
                GoogleCloudMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE, null);`

Gives `Cannot resolve symbol 'projectID'`

Comment: You have to define a string projectID in the strings.xml with your value: "79424738XXXX" than your code should work.

Comment: Okay, I figured out to put `gcm_defaultSenderId` containing my projectID in `strings.xml` but now the whole line gives IOException. @mrtn Yup, just did. Now it throws `Unhandled exception: java.io.IOException`