# Android Studio `jdk1.7.0_51\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2`

Tags: android, android-studio

I am all of a sudden getting the following issue when I try to build my application:

```
at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger$6.updateIndex(DexMerger.java:502)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger$IdMerger.mergeSorted(DexMerger.java:277)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeMethodIds(DexMerger.java:491)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:168)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:502)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:334)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:277)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:245)
    at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2'
```

From reading other threads it has something to do with having more than 65k methods. however My app is no where near that many, it is still a small app. Im not sure if that includes additional libraries included in the gradle file.

here is my gradle file:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.1'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.domain.app"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile files('libs/jasypt-1.9.2.jar')
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zbar:1.6.3'
    compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0'
    compile 'com.astuetz:pagerslidingtabstrip:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.mobsandgeeks:android-saripaar:2.0.3'
    compile 'com.github.satyan:sugar:1.3.1'
    compile 'uk.co.ribot:easyadapter:1.5.0@aar'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'
}
```

How can I determine If I am reaching this limit, If so is there a way to see which included library is so large?  Also what are the drawbacks to enabling `multiDexEnabled true`?

If I must be honest I would rather not enable multiDex and this application should not be this large. I would rather fix the source of the problem.

Comment: *Im not sure if that includes additional libraries included in the gradle file* - it does. Often `google-play-services` is the cause of this

Comment: remove  `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` as you already add  `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0'`

Comment: Does one need to include `com.google.gms.google-services' ? Or does the android OS include it?

Answer (score 1):

This eror happens because you have more than 65k methods which exceeds the capacity of dex.

You can use this lib to check if you have more than 65k methods or not https://github.com/KeepSafe/dexcount-gradle-plugin

You should had to your gradle if you have more than 65k and you need them

```
 defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.domain.app"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        multiDexEnabled true // Add this
    }
```

Please check the documentation here http://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html

Although if you do not need all methods of play-services use what you really need, you should check this documentation to use what you only need.
https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup

Additionally, as @IntelliJAmiya said remove this

```
 apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

because is duplicated, you are already using

```
'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0'
```

Answer (score 1):

add this to your build grandle

```
android {
.....
 multiDexEnabled true
}
```

and add multidex to your dependencies and try to build again

```
dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
}
```

**EDIT :** add in your manifest the mutltidex app :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.android.multidex.myapplication">
    <application
        ...
        android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication">
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

**EDIT 2 :** OR, if you have a class who extends Application, add `MultiDex.install(this)` in the `attachBaseContext()` of your class (override it if not exist)

Comment: I tried this, it build. But as I run I get loads of `NoClassDefFoundError`

Comment: Just to confirm. I must add `android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"` to my existing application manifest file?

Comment: I already have `<application
        android:name="com.orm.SugarApp"` for another library I am using.

Comment: So you have a class who extend Application? if the case, add MultiDex.install(this) to your attachBaseContext of your application without adding anything in your Manifest

Comment: I just googled and apparently SugaOrm doesn't work with multidex. So i'm pretty much stuck.

Comment: exactly, i saw it too it's a bug in SugarOrm lib, sorry i can't help you more, but if you find a solution please share it here, good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

Remove this at first

1. `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'`

   Actually you already call `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0'` .So don't need to call again .

Then Clean and Rebuild

Finally

```
    dependencies {
    compile files('libs/jasypt-1.9.2.jar')
    
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zbar:1.6.3'
    compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0'
    compile 'com.astuetz:pagerslidingtabstrip:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.mobsandgeeks:android-saripaar:2.0.3'
    compile 'com.github.satyan:sugar:1.3.1'
    compile 'uk.co.ribot:easyadapter:1.5.0@aar'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'
}
```

**Edit 1**

call `multiDexEnabled true`

Looks

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.domain.app"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 23
     multiDexEnabled true
}
```

And add this

```
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
```

Comment: I have done this, now the following line is not building `String token = instanceID.getToken(getString(R.string.gcm_defaultSenderId),
                        GoogleCloudMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE, null);`  I do make use of pushnotifications

Comment: @Zapnologica Your issue is now solved related to your this question. Now asked another question with code.

Comment: @MD It is not, as I still cant build. I need the code to compile in order to see If I can debug the application to see if my original error has been resolved.

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30687052/googlecloudmessaging-instanceid-getinstance-registering-from-client](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30687052/googlecloudmessaging-instanceid-getinstance-registering-from-client)

Comment: @Zapnologica [refer this](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/start)

Comment: @MD so you are saying I don't need the android support library in order to make use of push notifications.

Comment: @Zapnologica No. you need that Library but refer my above comment and see what you gonna do in order to get `token` for new `GCM`